# How to work with column containg array in H2 database to get n 1 row

Tags: sql, arrays, h2

I am new to H2 database. I have 3 tables in database for example,

### table t1 :

| ID | desc | something | condition_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | EN 142868 151508 | XYZ | [4686, 4687] |

### table condition

| CONDITION_ID | desc | COLUMN3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4686 | desc1 | something1 |
| 4687 | desc2 | something2 |

And I need output like this

| ID | desc | t1something | joined Column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | EN 142868 151508 | XYZ | desc1 something1, desc2 somethin2 |

How to do this, I tried with array_contains, but its giving 2 rows as a result like' t1ID t1desc t1something joined Column 1 EN 142868 151508 XYZ desc1 something1 1 EN 142868 151508 XYZ desc2 somethin2

Please help. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group rows from table `T1` and aggregate rows from table `CONDITION`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE T1(ID INT, DESC VARCHAR, SOMETHING VARCHAR, CONDITION_ID INT ARRAY)
AS VALUES (1, 'EN 142868 151508', 'XYZ', ARRAY[4686, 4687]);

CREATE TABLE CONDITION(CONDITION_ID INT, DESC VARCHAR, COLUMN3 VARCHAR)
AS VALUES (4686, 'desc1', 'something1'), (4687, 'desc2', 'something2');

SELECT T1.ID, T1.DESC, T1.SOMETHING,
    LISTAGG(CONDITION.DESC || ' ' || CONDITION.COLUMN3, ', ') JOINED_COLUMN
FROM T1 LEFT JOIN CONDITION ON ARRAY_CONTAINS(T1.CONDITION_ID, CONDITION.CONDITION_ID)
GROUP BY T1.ID, T1.DESC, T1.SOMETHING;
> ID | DESC             | SOMETHING | JOINED_COLUMN
> -- | ---------------- | --------- | ----------------------------------
> 1  | EN 142868 151508 | XYZ       | desc1 something1, desc2 something2
```

If you want to exclude rows from `T1` without corresponding entries in `CONDITION`, use inner `JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`.

You may also want to add `WITHIN GROUP (ODRER BY some_columns)` clause to `LISTAGG` aggregate function if you need some exact order of entries:

```sql
LISTAGG(CONDITION.DESC || ' ' || CONDITION.COLUMN3, ', ')
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CONDITION.CONDITION_ID)
JOINED_COLUMN
```

Alternatively, you can use a subquery:

```sql
SELECT T1.ID, T1.DESC, T1.SOMETHING,
  (
    SELECT LISTAGG(CONDITION.DESC || ' ' || CONDITION.COLUMN3, ', ')
    FROM CONDITION
    WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(T1.CONDITION_ID, CONDITION.CONDITION_ID)
  ) JOINED_COLUMN
FROM T1;
```

Comment: If we have 2 array columns , what will be the query? I tried this  ....not working
                                   
 SELECT T1.ID, T1.DESC, T1.SOMETHING,
    LISTAGG(CONDITION.DESC || ' ' || CONDITION.COLUMN3, ', ') JOINED_COLUMN,      LISTAGG(source.DESC || ' ' || source.COLUMN3, ', ') JOINED_source
FROM T1 LEFT JOIN CONDITION ON ARRAY_CONTAINS(T1.CONDITION_ID, CONDITION.CONDITION_ID)                                                                                               LEFT JOIN source ON ARRAY_CONTAINS(T1.source_ID, source.source_ID)
GROUP BY T1.ID, T1.DESC, T1.SOMETHING;

Comment: I've just edited my answer. Take a look on alternative query with subquery, you can add multiple subqueries for all such columns and their linked tables in the same way.